# When my program runs automatically at startup, having trouble append text to file. Why?

Tags: c++, winapi

I made a program that runs automatically at startup, but my program does not perform the task of append text to the file when it runs automatically.

Here example code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
void AutoRun() {
        
    LONG key;
    std::string FP;
    char re[MAX_PATH];
    FP = std::string(re, GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, re, MAX_PATH));
    HKEY hkey;
    key = RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Currentversion\\Run", 0, KEY_WRITE, &hkey);
    if (key == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cout << "paketi yüklüyoruzzz";
        key = RegSetValueExA(hkey, "testzort", 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)FP.c_str(), strlen(FP.c_str()));
                RegCloseKey(hkey);
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Maga mapket müklenemedi:(: " << key;
    }
}
int main(){
    // open output file in append mode
    const char* output_filename = "testing.log";
    std::cout << "Logging output to " << output_filename << std::endl;
    output_file.open(output_filename, std::ios_base::app);
    AutoRun();
    output_file << "zozozort\n";
}
```

When I restart my computer after execute this code, not add my file like:

```text
zozozort
zozozort
```

What is the problem ?

NOTE: For the first time to run the regedit api, I ran the program with administrator mode when starting

Comment: C and C++ are "very" (for sufficiently broad definition of "very") different languages (even more when it comes to input/output). C tag removed.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Did you try to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the program? Do you know what a *current working directory* is? *Where* do you expect the file to be, and *why*? Did you check that the program actually runs on startup?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I dont try debug, i will... and yes I know current working directory I expect file will be same directory with my program, all this to solve the problems in my head. And I'm pretty sure in startup, program is working too

Comment: Okay, so the next step is to check, when the program runs at startup, what the current working directory is (maybe you can research how to determine that, and then have the program print it). Next, look if there is a file there.

Comment: seems like code that would not compile. e.g. output_file not declared anywhere

Answer (score 3):

First off, consider using `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` instead of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` (unless you really want all users of your machine running your app). And consider using `KEY_SET_VALUE` instead of `KEY_WRITE` (which includes rights you don't need in this code).  This will reduce the need for your code to run as an admin when setting up the auto-run.

In any case, when calling `RegSetValueEx()`, you are setting the data size to `strlen(FP.c_str())`, which is wrong, as [`RegSetValueEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetvalueexa) requires the null terminator to be included in the data size:

> If the data is of type REG_SZ, REG_EXPAND_SZ, or REG_MULTI_SZ, **cbData must include the size of the terminating null character or characters.**

So, use `strlen(FP.c_str())+1` instead, or better `FP.size()+1`.

That being said, your app is opening the text file using a **relative** path, so its location is relative to the app's *current working directory*, which you don't know what it is when your app is started (you can use [`GetCurrentDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory) to determine that). Just because the *text file* is in the same folder as your app doesn't mean the *working directory* points to your app's folder. Always use **absolute** paths when creating/opening files.

If you were using `CreateFile()` instead of `(o)fstream` (BTW, where is your `output_file` variable declared?) to create/open the file, then you could use [`GetFinalPathNameByHandle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfinalpathnamebyhandlea) to determine its actual full path, so you can see if it is what you are expecting.

If your really want to create/open the text file in your app's folder, you already know how to get the app's full file path from `GetModuleFileName()`, so simply replace the filename portion after the last `'\'` character with your text file's name, and then use that full path to create/open the file.  Just make sure your app is not running in a folder that denies write access to non-admins, such as `Program Files`.

You really should be writing the text file into a folder that is guaranteed to be accessible to the calling user (preferably within their own profile), instead of in the app's folder.  For instance, get a user-accessible folder path via either:

- [`SHGetFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpatha), specifying something like `CSIDL_(LOCAL_|COMMON_)APPDATA`, `CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY`, `CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS`, etc.
- [`SHGetKnownFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath), specifying something like `FOLDERID_(Roaming|Local)AppData`, `FOLDERID_ProgramData`, `FOLDERID_Desktop`, `FOLDERID_Documents`, etc.

Then, create your own subfolder underneath that folder, and create the file inside that subfolder.